# Transfer request's file from API to API: NestJS(HttpService: Axios) to Python(flask)

Tags: javascript, node.js, flask, axios, nestjs

I am trying transfer a file from a nestJS API to Python Flask API.

This process will be triggered by a POST request (FormData: file) on nest API. Then the nest api should send the file to Python api.

The HttpService from nestJS use Axios. So my goal is basically to send file with axios from NodeJS.

FormData is not available on node JS so I installed [Nmp FormData](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) .

## Python

Python Code, which I think is working properly because Postman request pass without any problems.

```py
@app.route('/route', methods=['POST'])
def user():

    params_data = json.load(request.files.get('file'))

    return 'OK'
```

## NestJS

On the nest side, I tried a lot a things.

But the main idea is the following:
Use formData.getHeaders as axios headers and put data inside the axios config.

#### app.controller.ts

```js
    @Post()
    uploadFile(@Req() request: Request) {
        // request is Express request
        const formData: any = new FormData();
        let newFile;
        if (request.hasOwnProperty('file')) {
            newFile = (request as any).file; // This is working 
        }
        formData.append('file', newFile.buffer, 'filename');

        return this.appService.launchOptim(formData);
    }
```

#### app.service.ts

```js
  public launchOptim(modelData: FormData) {

    const axiosConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      headers: modelData.getHeaders(),
      data: modelData,
    };


    return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/route', modelData, axiosConfig)
               .pipe(map(result => result.data));

  }
```

And then, with that configuration, `request.files` in python code stays always empty.

How to correctly transfer request's file to another api with axios ?

Issue about this topic:
[Axios issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1006)
Also tried this
[Axios fix](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1892)

Comment: Hey Hugo, did you ever managed to get this working? I have a similar requirement... though for me I don't control the other API.

Comment: We used an alternative solution. I can't help on that, sorry :'(

Answer (score 6):

```
@Post()
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
uploadFile(@Req() request: Request, @UploadedFile() file,) {
    var FormData = require("form-data");
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file.buffer, { filename: file.originalname });
    const headers = {
        ...formData.getHeaders(),
        "Content-Length": formData.getLengthSync()
    };
    await axios.post(requestAPI, formData, { headers });
}
```

Comment: This example is useful, but could use some information. Can you edit your post specifically about what the asker needs to change to have this work, so that they (and future people who end up on this question) can better understand what went wrong for the end user?